# How to run Angular 2 (cli) without build?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I use  `Angular 2` `CLI`. In order to run the project for debugging, have to execute `ng build` or `ng serve`. It is too long.
Before, when I used 2 `Angular` Quick Start `package.json` there was an opportunity to execute a command that compiles the `just-in-time` and `instantly` returns the result.

How do the same on the cli?

Answer (score 0):

With Anguar CLI you need to run ng serve once. It starts the webpack-dev-server and keeps it running. You can start debugging and changing code, and webpack-dev-server will be automatically recompiling your code and re-building the bundles in memory every time you modify your code. All this happens as fast as with SystemJS transpiling in the browser.